# How to fix Linux Mint Software Sources GUI IsADirectoryError?

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation

On my linux mint machine i'm trying to enable universal repository from Software Sources.

While trying to open GUI with `sudo mintsources` i get an error saying

```bsh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/linuxmint/mintSources/mintSources.py", line 1691, in <module>
    Application().run()
  File "/usr/lib/linuxmint/mintSources/mintSources.py", line 847, in __init__
    file = open(source_file, "r", encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore")
IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/etc/apt/sources.list'
```

Comment: What did you do that `/etc/apt/sources.list` became a directory?

Comment: I was having that issue since months. But noticed the issue while i was trying to install `tree` package.

Answer (score 1):

Unless something is seriously wrong, the repository universe is enabled by default in Linux Mint. You can check the repositories with the following commands

```
grep -v '#' /etc/apt/sources.list | sed -e /^$/d
grep -v '#' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* | sed -e /^$/d
```

and if universe is not found by those commands, you can try with the command lines

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
```

---

I use the following command line to keep my system up to date,

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade
```

Some systems may have some program packages, that are not fully compatible, and therefore avoid `full-upgrade`. See `man apt-get` to get more details. For example, the following command lines can help when problems,

```
sudo apt -f install
sudo apt update
```

and either

```
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

or

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: Still the issue persists. My issue is not about being unable to install package. I just want to fix the mintsources GUI.

Comment: @SuryaBhusal, Did you try to reinstall the mintsources GUI? Or purge and then reinstall it? If still failing, maybe there is a bug (and if you cannot find a bug report about it, please create a bug report). Until it is fixed, you can try to install and use `synaptic` (from the repository universe). It is a good GUI package manager.